# Was bedeutet "potthässlich sein"?

Tags: etymology

Neulich befand meine Frau ein Kleid als *potthässlich*.

Umgangssprachlich habe ich das auch schon häufig benutzt, aber nun habe ich mich gefragt, worauf sich das eigentlich bezieht? Was soll der Ausdruck *pott* hier, mit welcher Hässlichkeit wird hier verglichen?

Comment: Diese Frage scheinen sich auch schon andere gestellt zu haben; bisher konnte ich allerdings nichts zur Etymologie des Wortes finden. Womöglich könnte es sich auf den Nachttopf beziehen: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pott#Bedeutung1b

Das ist aber selbstredend bloß Spekulation.

Comment: Zumindest scheint es erst seit 1970 verwendet zu werden: [Ngramm](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=potth%C3%A4sslich%2C+potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3) (oder früher getraute sich niemand es in Büchern zu verwenden ;) )

Comment: @knut Diesen Verdacht habe ich auch: Google findet das Wort nirgendwo im Projekt Gutenberg, und meine Jubiläumsausgabe der Digitalen Bibliothek (eine ganze DVD voller Texte vor 1930) enthält es auch nicht.

Comment: @knut Der älteste Treffer, den ich bei Google Books gefunden habe, ist ein [Film-Transkript von 1964](http://books.google.de/books?id=5TNeAAAAIAAJ&q=%22potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich%22&dq=%22potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=nD0XVLuXJI_qaLTqgcAL&redir_esc=y). (Aus den beiden genannten Personen schließe ich auf "Nazarín" von Luis Buñuel, gedreht 1959). Wenn das Wort damals schon in einer Übersetzung / Synchronisierung verwendet wurde, müßte es eigentlich schon eine Weile gebräuchlich gewesen sein, oder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verlässliche Quellen zur Etymologie des hier als Elativ gebrauchten "pott-" in *potthässlich* scheint es nicht zu geben.

Meine Recherchen haben ergeben:

- **potthässlich/potthäßlich** ist ein neues Wort, das erstmals Anfang der 60er Jahre in deutschen Schriften auftaucht ([Spectaculum, Suhrkamp 1964](http://books.google.de/books?ei=Wd4XVM7fEqKaygOtqYLYBA&hl=de&id=5TNeAAAAIAAJ&dq=potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich) und [Herrmann Moers: Liebesläufe 1964](http://books.google.de/books?id=_iLbAAAAMAAJ&q=potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich&dq=potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Wd4XVM7fEqKaygOtqYLYBA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ))
- **pott-** wird in älteren Schriften [nur vereinzelt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15691) als Elativ oder pejoratives Präfix gebraucht, dann meist im Kontext des Kohlebergbaus.
- In der Bedeutung **Pott** (ein [altes] Gefäß), könnte ein Zusammenhang bestehen (siehe *[Ruhrpott](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15688/)*), jedoch erscheint hier eine die Region wie ein "Gefäß" umschließende Bedeutung im Vordergrund zu stehen (und nicht so sehr die Schäbigkeit dieses Gefäßes). Somit kann man eine Übertragung dieses *Potts* auf ein pejoratives Präfix nicht ohne weitere vornehmen (zumindest gibt es keine verlässlichen Quellen, die dies belegen würden).
- Vor allem das späte Auftauchen von *potthässlich* legt eine Analogie mit dem amerikanischen Slangwort **[butt-ugly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/butt)** nahe. Diese Wendung soll bei den amerikanischen GIs im 2. Weltkrieg aufgetaucht sein. Es mag also sein, dass es sich um den gelungenen Versuch gehandelt hat, hier eine möglichst ähnliche klingende deutsche Übersetzung zu finden, bei der man sich des vereinzelt auftretenden [*pott-* aus dem Kohlebergbau](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15691) bediente. Auch das ist aber leider nirgends verlässlich belegt.

Comment: _butt-ugly_ ist ein toller Fund! "Diese Wendung soll bei den amerikanischen GIs im 2. Weltkrieg aufgetaucht sein." Hast Du dafür eine Quelle? Bei Ngramm scheint das Wort noch später aufzutauchen als `potthäßlich`. Theoretisch könnte es also auch anders herum gelaufen sein.

Comment: Die "Quelle" ist eine 2-fache Erwähnung in Slang-Dictionaries, vermutlich voneinander abgeschrieben, also leider nicht verlässlich... In USA findet man butt-ugly erst so richtig ab den 80er Jahren... also schon ein wenig dubios, aber irgendwie halt auch plausibel. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Auch ich kann leider nur einen "educated guess" abgeben:

Der Duden erklärt die Herkunft des Schimpfwortes "[Pottsau](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pottsau)" mit "im Dreck suhlende Sau" und gibt dabei an "Pott in der Bedeutung »Abfalleimer«". [Pott](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pott) ist ein im nord-/niederdeutschen Sprachraum verbreiteter Ausdruck für Topf oder ähnliche Gefäße (z.B. auch in "[Pisspott](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pisspott)" für "Nachttopf", im Märchen vom [Fischer und seiner Frau](http://www.maerchenatlas.de/grimms-marchen/vom-fischer-und-seiner-frau/) Bezeichnung für eine Kate, eine ärmliche Fischerhütte).

Das Rheinische Wörterbuch von 1928 kennt die Begriffe [pottschwarz](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/RhWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=RhWB&mode=Volltextsuche&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=RP06455), [pottdreckig](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/RhWB/?sigle=RhWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=RP06395) und [pottschmierig](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/RhWB/?sigle=RhWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=RP06450), die vermutlich einerseits auf Kohle- und Dreckeimer verweisen, in denen andererseits aber auch "pott" jeweils eine verstärkende Rolle zu übernehmen scheint. "Potthäßlich" hingegen ist dort noch nicht aufgeführt.

Meine Vermutung wäre nun, daß in Analogie dazu irgendjemand mal "pott" vor "häßlich" gesetzt hat, um den Ausdruck zu verstärken, insbesondere durch den Bezug auf etwas unsauberes, dreckiges. Eine sehr rudimentäre Textanalyse (siehe die Kommentare zur Frage; im Duden scheint der Begriff [seit mindestens 1972](http://books.google.de/books?id=-NYIAQAAIAAJ&q=%22potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich%22&dq=%22potth%C3%A4%C3%9Flich%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=7koXVMT4D-fG7Abd7oCIBg&redir_esc=y) vertreten zu sein) nährt den Verdacht, daß das etwa zwischen 1920 und 1950 geschehen sein könnte.

Comment: Pott kann man auch rauchen - sieht aber auch braun-schwarz aus, würde ich sagen. Was ist Pottasche? Jedenfalls was ordentliches.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist nichts neues, daß derselbe Wortbestandteil in verschiedenen Wörtern unterschiedliche  Funktionen haben kann. Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pottasche) heißt die Pottasche so, weil sie durch Kochen von Pflanzenasche in Töpfen = Pötten gewonnen wurde. Ein Haus hat auch keinen *blitz*blanken *Blitz*ableiter (wenn es nicht sehr neu ist).

Answer (score 4):

Könnte sein, dass der Ausduck aus dem Ruhrgebiet stammt aus einer Zeit als der Kohlebergbau noch sehr aktiv war. Wo Kohle abgebaut wurde, war die Gegend schmutzig und häßlich. Man hatte den Eindruck, dass alles vom Kohlenstaub schwarz war, sogar die Blätter der Bäume. Man bezeichnete das Kohlerevier abwertend als Kohlenpott und der Ausdruck könnte seine Herkunft aus der Formel haben: häßlich wie alles im Kohlenpott, kurz: potthäßlich.

Der Beitrag von Matthias gibt mir auch noch eine andere Idee. Es könnte sich um einen Pott (Topf) handeln, der immer auf alten Kohleherden stand, um warmes Wasser zu haben.Bei diesen alten Kohleherden konnte man aus der eisernen Herdplatte
Ringe direkt über der Feuerstelle entnehmen. Wenn man den Pott dann direkt auf dieses offene Loch stellte, wurde das Wasser schnell heiß, weil das Feuer direkt den Boden des Potts erhitzte. Natürlich war dieser Pott von außen auch verrußt und damit potthäßlich.

Answer (score -3):

Ich habe keine Quellen die dies belegen, aber "pott-" könnte aus "spott-" entstanden sein.
Also:

> "Dieses Kleid ist spotthässlich!" -> "Dieses Kleid ist potthässlich!"